# Where should properties like "SERVER_URL" live in a gradle-based Android project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Where should I define constants like SERVER_URL or some static passwords in a Gradle Android project? Obviously, I will use it in code.

1. In `build.gradle` file as a build config field
2. In `gradle.properties` file (I don't know how get these properties by code)
3. In another `props` file located in `res` folder

How secure is it in each case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches in your question.

> 1> To store static URL in your application

The fact someone can see the URL doesn't matter (they could get this by sniffing the network anyway). You probably want to ensure the request has come from a trusted client. You can also maintain some key in request also.

> 2> To store password in your application

I found a good solution to store it in **SharedPreferences** with encryption. Copy/Paste below code to create encrypted SharedPreferences.

Simply wrap your own SharedPreferences object in this one, and any data you read/write will be automatically encrypted and decrypted. eg.

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = new ObscuredSharedPreferences( 
this, this.getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) );

// eg.    
prefs.edit().putString("test","test").commit();
prefs.getString("test", null);
```

Class code,

```
/**
 * Warning, this gives a false sense of security.  If an attacker has enough access to
 * acquire your password store, then he almost certainly has enough access to acquire your
 * source binary and figure out your encryption key.  However, it will prevent casual
 * investigators from acquiring passwords, and thereby may prevent undesired negative
 * publicity.
 */
public class ObscuredSharedPreferences implements SharedPreferences {
    protected static final String UTF8 = "utf-8";
    private static final char[] SEKRIT = ... ; // INSERT A RANDOM PASSWORD HERE.
                                               // Don't use anything you wouldn't want to
                                               // get out there if someone decompiled
                                               // your app.


    protected SharedPreferences delegate;
    protected Context context;

    public ObscuredSharedPreferences(Context context, SharedPreferences delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class Editor implements SharedPreferences.Editor {
        protected SharedPreferences.Editor delegate;

        public Editor() {
            this.delegate = ObscuredSharedPreferences.this.delegate.edit();                    
        }

        @Override
        public Editor putBoolean(String key, boolean value) {
            delegate.putString(key, encrypt(Boolean.toString(value)));
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Editor putFloat(String key, float value) {
            delegate.putString(key, encrypt(Float.toString(value)));
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Editor putInt(String key, int value) {
            delegate.putString(key, encrypt(Integer.toString(value)));
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Editor putLong(String key, long value) {
            delegate.putString(key, encrypt(Long.toString(value)));
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Editor putString(String key, String value) {
            delegate.putString(key, encrypt(value));
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public void apply() {
            delegate.apply();
        }

        @Override
        public Editor clear() {
            delegate.clear();
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean commit() {
            return delegate.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public Editor remove(String s) {
            delegate.remove(s);
            return this;
        }
    }

    public Editor edit() {
        return new Editor();
    }


    @Override
    public Map<String, ?> getAll() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); // left as an exercise to the reader
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue) {
        final String v = delegate.getString(key, null);
        return v!=null ? Boolean.parseBoolean(decrypt(v)) : defValue;
    }

    @Override
    public float getFloat(String key, float defValue) {
        final String v = delegate.getString(key, null);
        return v!=null ? Float.parseFloat(decrypt(v)) : defValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int getInt(String key, int defValue) {
        final String v = delegate.getString(key, null);
        return v!=null ? Integer.parseInt(decrypt(v)) : defValue;
    }

    @Override
    public long getLong(String key, long defValue) {
        final String v = delegate.getString(key, null);
        return v!=null ? Long.parseLong(decrypt(v)) : defValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(String key, String defValue) {
        final String v = delegate.getString(key, null);
        return v != null ? decrypt(v) : defValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(String s) {
        return delegate.contains(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener onSharedPreferenceChangeListener) {
        delegate.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(onSharedPreferenceChangeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener onSharedPreferenceChangeListener) {
        delegate.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(onSharedPreferenceChangeListener);
    }




    protected String encrypt( String value ) {

        try {
            final byte[] bytes = value!=null ? value.getBytes(UTF8) : new byte[0];
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(SEKRIT));
            Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.ANDROID_ID).getBytes(UTF8), 20));
            return new String(Base64.encode(pbeCipher.doFinal(bytes), Base64.NO_WRAP),UTF8);

        } catch( Exception e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    protected String decrypt(String value){
        try {
            final byte[] bytes = value!=null ? Base64.decode(value,Base64.DEFAULT) : new byte[0];
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(SEKRIT));
            Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.ANDROID_ID).getBytes(UTF8), 20));
            return new String(pbeCipher.doFinal(bytes),UTF8);

        } catch( Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit**

You can use NDK to store password constant. To store and retrieve your key, you need to write the following code in our application.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("library-name");
}

public native String getSecretKey();
```

And save in a file using NDK the following function

```
Java_com_example_exampleApp_ExampleClass_getSecretKey( JNIEnv* env,
                                              jobject thiz )
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "giveMeSecretKey".");
}
```

Now you can easily retrieve our key and use it to encrypt our data.

```
byte[] keyPassword = getSecretKey().getBytes();
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to define the password at compile time. For instance, server http basic auth credentials. Where should I define this constant?

Comment: @bigdestroyer will that password be constant everytime?

Comment: Yes, Chintian. It will

Comment: As per my knowledge, if you store password anyway in your application, it will definitely be accessed or decrypted anyway. Coz if you encrypt it, you have to store key in plain text. Wait for a while I have another approach to store password constant statically.

Comment: Definitely, I love this way. It seems to be secure. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to define every sensitive value in gradle.properties, and ensure that this file is excluded from VCS. You can then get Gradle to add string resources into your build, which are accessible in the normal way. This has the added advantage that you can use different values for different product flavors.

```
// gradle.properties

MY_SECRET_PASSWORD=password



// build.gradle

buildTypes {
    debug {
        resValue "string", "my_secret_password", MY_SECRET_PASSWORD
    }
}


// MainActivity.java
String password = getString(R.string.my_secret_password);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this way secure enough?

Comment: You would be able to decompile the APK & find the URL (but you'd probably be able to figure this out from watching network traffic anyway)

Comment: It is secure enough for URLs (as @fractalwrench says, they can be discovered by sniffing the network traffic) but absolutely **NOT** for passwords. It is easier than you think to decompile the code and the String password value would be visible **in plain text** in the decompiled APK.

Comment: Moreover, you don't usually exclude .gradle files from VCS